# Run function from a package by reflecting its name

Tags: go

Currently I have the package name as a string `"Forecast"` and I need to reflect this string into a package so that I can call the function `Run()`. Is there a way to make this reflection?

**Why?**

Currently I am building a task runner in golang in which all tasks have the function `Run()` and I receive which task to run by a kafka message `"task": "Forecast"`, so I am trying to avoid a `switch` like:

```
switch message.Task {
  case "Forecast":
    Forecast.Run()
  case "SupplyCalculator":
    SupplyCalculator.Run()
}
```

And instead to just reflect the name and call the function, like this (PHP):

```
$task = new ReflectionClass("\\Task\\{$message->task}");
$task->run();
```

Comment: You can't use reflection on packages in Go. If you don't like using a `switch`, consider using a map instead.

Comment: have you considered using `go generate` to generate the switch statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packages are not a type in Go.

Given a package `foo` with a function `Run`, this works...

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(foo.Run)
fmt.Println(v.Kind()) // func
```

But this is a syntax error:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(foo)
```

Instead of trying to use reflection, register the functions ahead of time in a map, and then look up the correct function in that map to call it. You can provide a simple `tasks` package to do this, with methods like `Register` and `Run`.

```
// tasks.go
package tasks

type TaskFunc func() error // or whatever arguments your tasks take
var taskFuncs = map[string]TaskFunc{}

func Register(name string, fn TaskFunc) {
  taskFuncs[name] = fn
}

func Run(name string) error {
  if fn, found := taskFuncs[name]; found {
    return fn()
  }
  return fmt.Errorf("Task %q not found", name)
}
```

```
// forecast.go
package forecast

import "tasks"

tasks.Register("forecast", Run)

func Run() error {
   // ...
}
```

```
// main.go

err := tasks.Run(message.Task)
```

Comment: This is the way to do it :+1:

Comment: Your `forecast.go` is invalid - a bare function call isn't allowed at the top level. This should be inside an `init()` function.

Comment: @Adrian Pseudocode that isn't intended to run. You'll also note that `main.go` is an equally invalid snippet.

Comment: @meagar you might want to make that more clear in the answer then. The `main.go` snippet looks partial, the `forecast.go` snippet does not; it looks like it is intended to portray a complete go file.